# howto deploy application on dotcloud

Tags: web-deployment, dotcloud

I want to deploy a web.py application on dotcloud.
I followed the tutorial, http://docs.dotcloud.com
I idd this:
$ dotcloud create myapp
$ dotcloud push myapp .

after a long time waiting,i got this message:

2011-06-28 18:59:12 [api] Waiting for the build. (It may take a few minutes)
........................................................................Cannot reach DotCloud service ("[Errno -2] Name or service not known").
Please check the connectivity and try again.

Any ideas?

Comment: It happens to me too from time to time. I just try later on and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please check the connectivity and try again.

There isn't really much else to do. You don't get any errors, the build system isn't broken (works for me), dotcloud isn't down.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with DNS resolution.
If you are behind a proxy server then you'll have to configure your system such that the dotcloud app makes connections through your proxy.